# Why can you not use anon function with a dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, dynamic, anonymous-function

Just ran into this today

> An anonymous function or method group cannot be used as a constituent
>   value of a dynamically bound operation.

when trying to do

```
static R ifNotNull<R>(dynamic o, Func<dynamic, R> returnFunc, R otherwise) {
    return ReferenceEquals(null, o) ? otherwise : returnFunc(o);
}
```

and use it with

```
dynamic firstAddress = ...;
return ifNotNull<string>(firstAddress, (a) => a.address_1, null)
```

Now most of the limitations on dynamics make sense to me - you can't use an extension method because how is the compiler supposed to decide which static to compile it to? But I don't get this here. Where does the confusion come in? What exactly is the limitation?

Comment: There's probably an issue with compiling `(a) => a.address_1` into a `returnFunc`. Waiting for Eric Lippert to answer this question :-)

Comment: By the way, what's the difference between your code and `static R ifNotNull<R>(object o, Func<object,R> returnFunc, R otherwise) {...}`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight exactly what I was thinking. Prepare to Lippert in 3..2..1...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the ability to do `ifNotNull<string>(firstAddress, (a) => a.address_1, null)`

Comment: @RohitHarkhani Indeed! I really don't understand this limitation.

Comment: Not sure this is working  Func<dynamic, string> func = (a) => a.address_1;
            return ifNotNull<string>(firstAddress, func, null);

Comment: Yes, you can. But you need to cast it.

Comment: @CliveDM .... so you can't then... once you cast a dynamic parameter its obviously not dynamic anymore and the compiler won't treat it as such.

Comment: I mean you need to cast the `lambda` expression, see my answer down below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What is the static type of the [lamba](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) `a => a.address_1`?  You may be tempted to say it's a `Func<dynamic, dynamic>`.  But remember:

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types.

So maybe it's an `Expression<Func<dynamic, dynamic>>`.  A lamda by itself doesn't have a single static type.

Now normally type inference would figure out that you're passing the lamba to a function that takes a `Func` and it will be converted to a delegate at compile time. However when you are calling with dynamic arguments [the method call is dispatched dynamically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/04/01/errata-dynamic-conversions-and-overload-resolution.aspx).

> If you have a method call with a dynamic argument, it is dispatched
>   dynamically, period. During the runtime binding, **all the static types
>   of your arguments are known** (emphasis mine), and types are picked for the dynamic
>   arguments based on their actual values.

So the fact that your method takes a `Func` isn't take into account, since [the actual method call isn't determined until runtime](http://ericlippert.com/2012/10/22/a-method-group-of-one/) so there is no type inference.

To get this to compile you'll have to cast your lamba to a `Func<dynamic, string>` as below:

```
return ifNotNull<string>(firstAddress, new Func<dynamic, string>((a) => a.address_1), null);
```

Now the static type of your lamda is known.

Comment: Thanks for the solid reply. That makes sense. Though I'm still kinda bummed I didn't get a lippert answer...

Answer (score 2):

I meant that you need to cast the `lambda` method to the expect expression you want. Then it'll work just fine.

Like this:

```
return ifNotNull(firstAddress, (Func<dynamic, string>)((a) => a.address_1), null);
```